# Display diff in Linux dialog textbox

Tags: linux, textbox, dialog, diff

I am trying to display a file in a Linux dialog textbox that was created with this command (the file that is):

```
diff -u --ignore-all-space $FILE $NEWFILE${FILE#$OLDFILE} >> $tempfile1
```

The command for the textbox is

```
        dialog --backtitle "$BACKTITLE"\
        --begin 3 5\
        --title "Differences in files found"\
        --textbox $tempfile1  $(( `tput lines` - 10 ))  $(( `tput cols` - 10 ))
```

Only part of the file is displayed. The lines starting with "---", "+++" and "@@" are displayed. The lines starting with "-" or "+" are suppressed. Does anybody know how I can display the whole file?
I tried changing the output format of diff but that didn't change the way the dialog box displayed the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Though I'm on a linux box the resulting diff file showed "^M" in vim. So when I dos2unixed the file it was displayed correctly in the dialog textbox.